# How to change font size in dynamic list view in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have strange problem with code.

When I change font size dynamically the static listItem text changed. But dynamic listitem text not changing.

Here is the code:

```
 <List
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#3F51B5",
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            <ListItem>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: this.state.fontSize,
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: "white"
                }}
              >
               Hello
              </Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
```

**Font size change in above code is working.**

```
<List
            dataArray={this.state.data}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            renderRow={item => (
              <ListItem
                noBorder
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center"
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={
                    {
                      fontSize: this.state.fontSize,
                      textAlign: "center"
                    }
                  }
                >
                  {item.line}
                </Text>
              </ListItem>
            )}
          />
```

**Font size change in above code is Not working.**

What is the problem? Anyone please help. It is strange issue. Static list text font-size changing but dynamic not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the List component in Native Base is only updated when there is a change in the dataArray prop. So an update in `this.state.fontSize` is not recognised by List so there will be no re-render.

Native Base also warns that `List` isn't suitable for dynamic lists, and advises to use the standard react-native `FlatList` component:

> Note: List is deprecated. Use of List for dynamic list generation is
>   discouraged.For more advanced implementation of rendering list
>   dynamically, take a look at nativebase-tutorial. Use Flatlist instead.

When changing List for FlatList, you can specially state that `this.state.fontSize` should update the component by passing it to the `extraData` prop.

```jsx
<List
  data={this.state.data}
  extraData={this.state.fontSize} // this will cause re-render for fontSize updates
  style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <ListItem
      noBorder
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: this.state.fontSize,
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {item.line}
        </Text>
      </ListItem>
    )}
  />
```